# Measurements Convert to Cups Unit

Tags: ios, swiftui

This is driving me nuts, would love some help. I'm using measurements in swiftui and need to convert mililitres to cups. The conversion is working OK, but I can't get the unit to display as cups, it keeps displaying as c, which is confusing, as it looks like centigrade.

capacityArray, is an array of ints, that are millilitre values.
eg
[100, 250, 450]

```
let capacity = Measurement(value: Double(capacityArray[0]), unit: UnitVolume.milliliters)

Text("* Capacity: \(capacity.converted(to: .cups).toString())")

Result:
    * Capacity: 0.85 c
```

My quick fix was to add "ups" to the end of the string, but this makes localization tricky.

```
Text("* Capacity: \(capacity.converted(to: .cups).toString())ups")

Result:
    * Capacity: 0.85 cups
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the implementation of `toString` but that's probably where the problem is. You need to specify the correct arguments for formatting the measurement and then the system can take care of things like localisation for you.

```
let capacity = Measurement(value: 100, unit: UnitVolume.milliliters)

let style = Measurement<UnitVolume>.FormatStyle
.measurement(
    width: .wide, 
    usage: .asProvided, 
    numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0...2))
)

print(capacity.formatted(style))
print(capacity.converted(to: .cups).formatted(style))
```

Gives

```
100 millilitres
0.42 cups
```

`width: .wide` tells the formatter to use the longest unit description. `usage: .asProvided` tells it not to convert to locally appropriate units.

Comment: Thank you, this is working great. It also works with localization. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach using `.value.magnitude` and `.unit.symbol` as shown in the example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let capacityArray = [100, 250, 450]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(capacityArray, id: \.self) { val in
            let capacity = Measurement(value: Double(val), unit: UnitVolume.milliliters)
            let cup = capacity.converted(to: .cups)
            HStack {
                Text("value: \(cup.value.magnitude)")
                Text(" \(cup.unit.symbol)")
            }
            // Text("Capacity: \(cup.description)")  // basic alternative
        }
    }
}
```

Note, since you have `capacityArray` in `milliliters`, there is also the `.metricCups` type.